# Why might $input (Settings API) be coming through empty?

Tags: theme-development, functions, options

I'm trying to be a good thememaker and pass all my settings through the Settings API, but I'm running into some difficulty in the sanitization callback function.

The core of the problem is this: the $input variable, passed in by default, is empty. My $_POST[options group] is coming through just fine (it has everything I'd expect to see in $input) but, again, $input is empty. Where do I even start looking to debug this?

**EDIT 1**

In response to Chip, here's what I have (stubbed, obviously):

```
function lblg_sanitize_options( $input ){
global $lblg_shortname, $lblg_default_options;

echo "Input: ";
print_r($input);
```

If I do something similar using, e.g., Oenology and do a `print_r($input);`, I get the expected `Array(` etc.

**EDIT 2**

Here's the results of `print_r($_REQUEST);` for my theme:

```
Array ( [option_page] => lblg_options [action] => update [_wpnonce] => 1f96eb2410 [_wp_http_referer] => /wp-admin/themes.php?page=lblg_options [lblg_options] => Array ( [layout_stylesheet] => Select a layout: [alt_stylesheet] => *none* [use_custom_header] => true [display_footer_copyright] => true [footer_copyright] => [footer_credit_text] => [save] => Save changes ) )
```

And here it is for Oenology:

```
Array ( [option_page] => theme_oenology_options [action] => update [_wpnonce] => 748c46a1a1 [_wp_http_referer] => /wp-admin/themes.php?page=oenology-settings [theme_oenology_options] => Array ( [header_nav_menu_position] => below [header_nav_menu_depth] => 1 [display_social_icons] => on [rss_feed] => rss2 [facebook_profile] => [flickr_profile] => [linkedin_profile] => [myspace_profile] => [twitter_profile] => [youtube_profile] => [display_footer_credit] => false [submit-general] => Save Settings ) )
```

I can't spot the difference. Can you?

**EDIT 3**

Might the various slugs/shortnames/pagenames be conflicting somehow?

**EDIT 4**

Here's what I'm doing for registration:

```
function lblg_admin_init(){
    global $lblg_shortname;
    register_setting( 'lblg_options', $lblg_shortname . '_lblg_options', 'lblg_sanitize_options' );
}
```

Here's what I'm calling out, intra-options-form:

```
settings_fields( 'lblg_options' ); 
do_settings_sections( 'lblg_options' );
```

The settings themselves are all being registered in a big loop, in a fashion similar to this:

```
add_settings_field( $key, $value['name'], '', 'lblg_options', $section );
```

Further thoughts?

Comment: Can you post (pastebin, etc.) your entire options code? Trying to piecemeal this might not be effective.

Comment: Chip: the code is lousy with debug messages, so it won't work at the moment, but here's an intermediate Hg format. https://bitbucket.org/zamoose/lblg/src/60ba9a5d09c9/functions.php https://bitbucket.org/zamoose/lblg/src/60ba9a5d09c9/includes/functions/admin.php and https://bitbucket.org/zamoose/lblg/src/60ba9a5d09c9/includes/functions/options.php

Comment: Or you could `hg clone http://bitbucket.org/zamoose/lblg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question by way of an answer Chip has embedded in his excellent [settings tutorial](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/?all=1&doing_wp_cron), namely: it's all about Correlating Function Arguments. Apparently some of the variable names/options group names I was using weren't lining up correctly.

Comment: That's the trickiest part sometimes, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

The `$input` variable is *not* passed to the validate function by *default*. You need to declare it, e.g. not *this*:

```
function mytheme_validate_settings() {}
```

But rather, **this**:

```
function mytheme_validate_settings( $input ) {}
```

(Or maybe I'm the only one who's made that bone-headed mistake before?) :)

EDIT:

The other thing to check: does the `$optiongroup` in `register_setting()` match the argument passed to `settings_fields()` in your form markup?

Comment: No, I've got that. I'm actually taking a page from your Oenology setup, it's just not working.

Comment: Next thing to check: `$optiongroup`. See edit.

Comment: Check the edits above.

Comment: Where is the `$optiongroup` passed into [`add_settings_field()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field)?

Comment: Arr, I see, it has to match the variable passed into [`settings_fields()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/settings_fields), not [`add_settings_field()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field).